# Order of Automorphis group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a finite solvable group and $ N $ be a normal minimal subgroup of $ G $ that $ G = MN $ for maximal subgroup $ M $ of $ G $, which $ M \cap N = 1 $. Let $ \vert N \vert = 4 $. Then $ \vert Aut(N) \vert = ? $ and $ \vert M \vert = ? $

Comment: $|M|$ could be any multiple of $3$.

Comment: $ \vert M \vert = 6 $ ?

Comment: If $G=A_4$ then $|M|=3$. If $G=A_4 \times C_n$ for some $n$, then $|M|=3n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ N $ is elementary abelian group of order $ 2^{2} $, then $ \vert Aut(N) \vert = (2^{2} - 2)(2^{2} - 1 ) = 6 $.

Comment: $ \vert M \vert = ? $